# How do I know a Linq expression has been autocompiled and the Query Plan cached?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, profiler

I have a very complex LINQ to SQL expression in an .Net 4.5 application that uses EF 6. The result is a very, very long SQL query, about 2700 rows.

Here is a simple test that calls a method in my service class.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void InmatningsmallServiceGetRows()
    {
        Guid id = new Guid("33a274f7-add7-49d7-ab0a-097d52e779ae");
        var children = ArchiveWork.ArchService.getChildrenByParentId(id).ToList();
        Assert.AreEqual(children.Count(), 0);
    }
```

In my service class:

```
public IQueryable<ArchiveRow> getChildrenByParentId(Guid id)
{
    var qChildren = (from rel in ArchiveRelRepo.Query()
         where rel.source_fk == id && rel.typ_fk == CodeArchiveRelation.Direct
         select rel
               );

    var qArchiveChildren = (from rel in qChildren
          let a = rel.table_archive_dest
          let date = a.table_archive_dates.FirstOrDefault(d => d.enhet_fk == a.enhet_id && d.datetyp_fk == CodeDateType.DTime)
          let relsToChildren = a.table_archive_rel_source
          let backwardRel = a.table_archive_rel_dest
          let term = a.table_archive_term
          orderby rel.sortkey
          select new ArchiveRow
          {
              Id = a.enhet_id,
              TypCode = a.typ_fk,
              IncrementalNumber = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)a.incNumber).Trim(),
              Title = a.name,
              From = date.startdate,
              Tom = date.slutdate,
              SortKey = rel.sortkey,
              NumberOfChildren = relsToChildren.Where(r => r.typ_fk == CodeArchiveRelation.Direct).Count(),
              TypeOfChildren = relsToChildren.Where(r => r.typ_fk == CodeArchiveRelation.Direct).Select(x => x.table_archive_dest.typ_fk).Distinct(),
              NumberOfReproduced = relsToChildren.Count(rr => rr.typ_fk == CodeArchiveRelation.Reproduced),
              NumberOfReferences_source = relsToChildren.Where(rh => rh.typ_fk == CodeArchiveRelation.SeAven || rh.typ_fk == CodeArchiveRelation.Se).Count(),
              NumberOfReferences_dest = backwardRel.Where(rl => rl.typ_fk == CodeArchiveRelation.Se).Count(),
              ArchivesReferencesSource = relsToChildren.Where(rh => rh.typ_fk == CodeArchiveRelation.SeAven || rh.typ_fk == CodeArchiveRelation.Se).Select(x => new Archive { ReferensCodeBas = x.table_archive_dest.referenceCode, Title = x.table_archive_dest.name }),
              ArchivesReferencesDest = backwardRel.Where(rl => rl.typ_fk == CodeArchiveRelation.Se).Select(x => new Archive { ReferensCodeBas = x.table_archive_source.referenceCode, Titel = x.table_archive_source.name }),
              TopographyReferences = term.Where(y => y.table_term.tes_fk == CodeTesaurus.Topography).Select(x => new ReferencesTerm { TermName = x.table_term.name, Specifikation = x.spec }),
              AmnesOrdReferences = term.Where(y => y.table_term.tes_fk != CodeTesaurus.Topography).Select(x => new ReferencesTerm { TermName = x.table_term.name, Specifikation = x.spec }),
              InstitutionReferences = a.table_archive_institution.Select(x => x.table_institution).Select(r => new Institution { referenceCode = r.referenceCode, Name = r.name }),
              LocationReferences = a.table_location_archive.Select(x => new LocationsReference { FranHyllaText = x.table_location_start.referenceCode, TillHyllaText = x.table_location_slut.referenceCode }),
              KallTyper = relsToChildren.Select(x => new ArkivTypRelTyp { RelTyp = x.typ_fk, ArkivTyp = x.table_archive_dest.typ_fk }),
              DestTyper = backwardRel.Select(x => new ArkivTypRelTyp { RelTyp = x.typ_fk, ArkivTyp = x.table_archive_source.typ_fk })
          }
       );

    return qArchiveChildren;
}
```

I run the test and it takes about 6 seconds to complete
[image]

But in Profiler the actual query seems to be executed quite fast.
[image]

The whole operation starts with and Audit Login and Logout that takes over 5 seconds. What is happening during this time (lets call it Initial Connection Time, ICT*)?

If I run a very simple test that just calls the Find method in the same dbContext it has an Initial Connection Time of about 3400 milliseconds. That seems to be some kind of minimum connection time. 
But what makes this duration time increase?
I have other equally complex queries as the one with an ICT of over 5700 milliseconds that have an ICT of about 3500 milliseconds.

Could it be that the autocompilation is prevented and EF is recompiling the LINQ expression every time? 
Is there a way to know if the query has been compilated and the query plan cached?

(*) ICT is my own nomenclature.

Comment: Are you sure that there is not a different query is fired to the database ? Did you check with SQL Profiler ?

Comment: Yes, I'm watching SQL Profiler while I'm debugging so I can see exactly when the query is actually fired.

Comment: I am wondering how long the query took according to SQL profiler and as measured inside dotnet ?